# VAR issue in Counter Strike Global Offensive

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I don't know how to fix this VAR issue, as you can see below the picture it's jumping from 0 ms to even 16 ms or 20 ms and it's causing lag. I tried to lower graphics.Putting NVIDIA to perfomance.Playing on high perfomance (laptop). On 1v1 servers it's better, but on other servers it's a disaster. I formated my laptop and it got like all laggy. But before I had no problem keeping the 60 FPS.

[image]

Comment: Did you try that on another server? Thats something that can caused by specific mods on a server

Comment: Yea, always, any casual, any deathmatch server

Answer (score 1):

You should :

- Try capping your FPS (fps_max 60)
- Set rate to 128.000 in your console (rate 128000)
- Shut down all other processes except steam and Csgo

Var depends on the server as well , maybe join a few.

Comment: I already tried that. I always disable antivirus, and exit from everything.